# IIS ASP.NET Impersonation on Windows 7 Possible?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, iis-express

I have written an asp.net web API which has a file reader/parser in the controller. When I run this via my Visual Studio environment, I am able to access files on our network fine (Z:\TestFile.txt). However, when I run from my localhost IIS 7.5, I get *Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\TestFile.txt'.*

I'm fairly certain this is a permission issue of some kind. To confirm this, I am able to read a file from the local C: easily from both visual studio IIS Express and my localhost IIS 7.5.

Why am I able to get success via Visual Studio IIS Express, but not via IIS 7.5. I am running on a windows 7 Machine. I have configured my ASP.NET 4.0 application pool to allow impersonation, and to impersonate with my credentials. Is it possible that Windows 7 with IIS doesn't allow the impersonation to pass through?

My web.config file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
        <identity impersonate="true" userName="MyDomain\MyUserID" password="MyPassword"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/ReadFile/*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: first of all, don't do that.  It's highly insecure.  Second of all, you should simply give the share permissions to allow your machine to access it.  By default, IIS worker processes uses the AppPoolIdentity which translates to Network Service.  This connects to network resources as the Machien name.  So you simply add your machine names credentials to the file share, as well as the directory permissions.

Comment: @Erik. Thanks for your reply. I can only assume that my local machine doesn't have access to the file share, but my userid does?  We run multiple robots, applications, and users through different machines and servers. A single application server may be running a service from another group which I don't want to access my files. If we just open files up the the entire machine, then they can also access my files and cause problems.

Comment: Then you should set the user identity of the AppPool.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx